# converting List<Object> to string array and sending email to multiple address using java mail

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

Hi I am trying to convert List to string array and sending multiple Attendees' email using java mail and it seemed to not work am I doing it right or not need advices here is the code thanks

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/createBooking/{location}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@PathVariable(value = "location") String location,
            @Validated @RequestBody Booking book) {
        book.setStatus("reserved");
        book.setBookingCode(generatedString);

        bookingRepository.save(book);

        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            String[] array = new String[book.getAtt().size()]; 
            int index = array.length;
            for (Object value : book.getAtt()) { 
                array[index] = String.valueOf( value );
                helper.setTo(array[index]);
            }
            sb.append("Agenda:" + " " + book.getBookingDesc()).append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("When:" +  " " + book.getDateBooked() + " " + book.getStartTime() + " " + "To" + " " + book.getEndTime())
                    .append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Where:" + " " + location).append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("By:" + " " + book.getBookedUser()).append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Booking code:" + " " + generatedString);
            helper.setText(sb.toString());
            helper.setSubject("Meeting");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Error while sending mail ..", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        sender.send(message);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Inputs have been saved", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

here is the error that is shown in the email

[image]

here is the model classes

Booking class

```
@Entity
public class Booking implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long bookingId;

    private String bookingDesc;

    private String bookedUser;

    private String bookedUserName;

    private String bookedEmail;

    private String bookingCode;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dateBooked;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+8")
    private Time startTime;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+8")
    private Time endTime;

    private String status;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")
    private List<Attendees> att = new ArrayList<Attendees>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_booked")
    private Room room;
// setters getters

}
```

here is the Attendees class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ref_attendees")
public class Attendees implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idRefAttendees;

    private String attendeesEmail;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trans_id")
    private Transaction tras;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Booking booking;
//setters getters

}
```

Here is how I pass data using postman

[image]

EDIT: I added the models that is related to the problem and added postman

Comment: You should not be posting user details publicly, like email id, name, etc. Also who does booking for 'Kings Landing'. ?

Comment: The user who is logged in

Comment: To convert the Attendees object to String array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using following code.

```java
List<Attendees> attendees = book.getAtt();
for (int i=0;i<attendees.size();i++) { 
    array[i] = attendees.get(i).getAttendeesEmail();
}
helper.setTo(array);
```

`book.getAtt().getAttendeesEmail()` will give you the email id, but `book.getAtt()` will give you the Attendees object which is visible (hashCode) on the error email as well.

**Addition: On Java 8**

```
String[] emails = attendees.stream().map(a -> a.getAttendeesEmail()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: it has an error saying getAttendeesEmail cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: The error is gone now but can't receive any email even an error

Comment: How is array[index] valid? Should it not give ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException??

Comment: I won't delete this code?    String[] array = new String[book.getAtt().size()]; 
   int index = array.length - 1;

Comment: @RahulAgrawal I should remove it?

Comment: Remove `int index = array.length;`

Comment: For testing could you just try setting a hardcode valid email address and check

Comment: Oh it worked I just forgot to remove the other setTo